# "Recent files" in visual studio seems to not be updated with recent files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I open a file in an editor of Visual Studio, I assume that the file will be added to the top of the list accessed with File→Recent Files.

However, that seems to not be the case.

Why not?

The list however contains files that are accessed not a long time ago, but I cannot conclude a general rule for what it contains and in which order.